# Why is passing mutex to thread not possible?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

Passing a mutex reference to a thread causes compile errors. Why is it not possible (I have multiple threads using the same shared variable), and how do I fix it?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<mutex>

void myf(std::mutex& mtx)
{
    while(true)
    {
        // lock 
        // do something
        // unlock
    }
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    std::mutex mtx;

    std::thread t(myf, mtx);

    t.join(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[`thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) copies its arguments:

> First the constructor copies/moves all arguments...

`std::mutex` is not copyable, hence the errors. If you want to pass it by reference, you need to use [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref):

```
std::thread t(myf, std::ref(mtx));
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b3178aa2b8f12b5)